# Django authenticate def not triggering logged_in_success and logged_in_fail signal

Tags: python, django

When i do authentication by  function

`from django.contrib.auth import authenticate`

Djnago is not triggering success/fail signal, if i use the function

`from django.contrib.auth import login`

it will trigger as expected . basically i want to trigger the signal from following function

```
user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
```

now i added extra line to my code

```
login(request, user)
```

after adding this , i am getting signal here

```
from django.contrib.auth.signals import (
    user_logged_in,
    user_login_failed,
)
```

How can i get signal just from authenticate def ? i am using this for API

Comment: Django only triggers the `user_login_failed` signal from `authenticate` function, not the success signal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django does not send `user_logged_in` signal from `authenticate`. It sends it from `login` as you can see [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py#L132). However, you can always trigger signal yourself.

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, user_logged_in


user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
user_logged_in.send(sender=user.__class__, request=request, user=user)
```

Or maybe write a function that does both.

Answer (score 2):

`authenticate` merely checks provided credentials and returns an `User` instance on success ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.authenticate)). It does not perform the actual logging in. That's done by the `login` function ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.login)). They are supposed to be used as you have.

`user_logged_in` signal is sent by `login` on success and `user_login_failed` is sent by `authenticate` when authentication fails.